# Changing a data structure and determining what the O notation is when it's transformed

Tags: javascript, big-o

When transforming a collection into a hash map:

```
[
  {[dynamic_key]: 'bonjour', lang: 'fr'},
  {[dynamic_key]: 'hello', lang: 'en'},
   ...
]
```

to this:

```
{
  dynamic_key: 'fr',
  dynamic_key: 'en',
  ...
}
```

Would the method to do this be considered n^3 or 3*n?

(data being from a json response and mapping over the items with spreading over the data)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```
Object.assign({}, ...data.map(item => ({[dynamic_key]: lang})));
```

(when in practice it would be just `n` ignoring the constant)

Would I be considered correct?

Comment: Where do `dynamic_key` and `lang` come from?

Comment: its just an id of some sort, that I dynamically create in js https://wtfruby.com/javascript/2017/01/04/js-dynamic-attr-names.html

Comment: how about testing it ? do a few trials with low n and a few tests with high n and take the time see how it changes

Comment: If people cannot understand the code you post, you're not likely to get a lot of useful help. The last bit of code (the `...data.map()` code) literally does not make any sense out of context.

Comment: In any case it's *definitely* not O(n^3) with just a single `.map()` call, unless there's a significant amount of code in that callback that you haven't posted.

Comment: No it just does the above.

Comment: For practical purposes you can consider the construction of a simple object like that a constant-time operation, so you've got an O(n) operation. It could probably be done a little more efficiently, like by using a single `.reduce()` call, but that's not likely to matter much.